# Fresh install after CPU upgrade

Tags: upgrade, performance, mac-pro, logic

When installing a program on a Mac does the installer consider processor speed and number of cores in order to tailor the programs performance, and if so will upgrading processor architecture from single to dual CPUs require reinstalling the program for improved performance.

I'm having trouble with the alignment or synchronization of sound and the visual feedback from the GUI in Apple's Logic Pro 10.2, when running more than 8 processing threads, which, now that I've installed two six core 3.46 GHz Intel Xeon 5690, is a meager count considering the 24 possible threads possible with hyperthreading.

Answer (score 1):

To fix that you will probably have to reinstall Mac OS X. To do that, hold the command key when you press the power button and when the system starts up, click the option to re install Mac OS X. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

In general, the installer won't care about the count of CPU. Even run-time, most programs won't check on the number of CPU and instead just make threads and throw it at the kernel for execution.

Software can certainly query the system on timing and Logic and other audio processing apps certainly do - but you might have made things worse if that program is hard coded to detect specific CPU types and doesn't see yours listed, so it assumes it's running on a less capable Mac.

I would start with documenting the basics from the command line to make sure the OS is seeing the correct lineup of CPU.

```
sysctl -a|grep ^hw|grep cpu
system_profiler SPHardwareDataType
```

If that matches, then you have a vendor support issue in Logic (or perhaps someone has patched the program to take better advantage of CPU upgrades). The OS itself doesn't make many decisions at install time, instead it polls the hardware at boot time, so you could power off the hardware, reset the NVRAM and then give the OS a clean look at what's installed and make sure the above output matches your expectations.